# How to evaluate this results in python with pandas or numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to evaluate the results of a dataframe

[image]

Those are soccer results. Where the score is INTEGER - INTEGER.
But the times when the match goes to penalty kicks, the results of the penalty kicks are before and after the integer (5) 1-1 (4) for example.

I wanted to see if any of you think of how can I can evaluate the results to show the winner of each match

I was going to try separating the column on the '-' but it's not enough for the penalty scores

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to find all the numbers:

```
import re
def split_scores(s):
  # regex to find all numbers
  scores = re.findall(r'\d+', s) 
  # if s = "(5) 12-6 (1)" scores will be ['5', '12', '6', '1']
  # if s = "2-5", scores will be ['2', '5']
  
  # add penalty 0 if no penalty
  if len(scores) == 2:
     scores = ['0'] + scores + ['0']
  # convert to int
  scores = [int(x) for x in scores]
  return scores

df['team1_penalty'], df['team1_score'], df['team2_score'], df['team2_penalty'] = \
    zip(*df['Score'].map(split_scores))
```